# Automatic popup on a web page after a specific delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am making a B2C website for elearning. I want that when users come to the website and they have been on a page for more than x seconds( say more than 15 seconds ) then a popup window opens up and this window will have some kind of a help message, say a message like "Questions ? We can help. Please call us on XXXXXXX or write to us at abc@xyz.com" . The popup will have a simple image in it and a close button on top right.

My question is that how can I achieve this behavior of an automatic popup coming after a specific delay , when the user is on the site. Also, I would like to have this popup on specific pages and not the complete site.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setTimeout() function in document.ready() and provide your function to it which generates the pop-up.
For more reference, check out http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 1):

just use javascript setTimeout Function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        yourPopupFunction();
    }, 15000));
})
```